# onProgressUpdate only called at the end of AsyncTask (socket creation)

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask

I'm trying to display a "waiting" dialog while the connection is being established by the socket. Do you have any idea why this bit of code is not working ?

onProgressUpdate gets called at the end of the doInBackground. I intend to show it before connectionSocket.connect times out.

The following bit

```
dialog = connection.dialog("progress");
        dialog.show();
```

works well on its own!

```
@Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... ip) {
        Log.i("CONNECTION","doInBackground : Creating socket");
        Boolean result = false;
        try {
            publishProgress();
            connectionSocket = new Socket();
            connectionSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip[0], connection.getServerPort()), 5000);
            publishProgress();
            Log.i("CONNECTION","doInBackground : Socket created");
            result = true;
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.i("CONNECTION","doInBackground : Error creating socket. UnknownHostException");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.i("CONNECTION","doInBackground : Error creating socket. IOException");
        }
        return result;
    }

   @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        Log.i("CONNECTION","onProgressUpdate");
        dialog = connection.dialog("progress");
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Thank you for helping :*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show the dialog in onPreExecute, instead of onProgressUpdate. OnProgressUpdate is to be used for long operations where you have specific percentage updates on the task at hand.

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog = connection.dialog("progress");
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Thankss, of course, it makes sense...  Still have some UI issues but it works as expected!